# Use random var in behat tests to produce unique usernames

Tags: behat

Right now I am creating users using something like the following

```
Given users:
| name | status | roles |
| kyle | 1 | authenticated user |
| cartman | 1 | admin |
```

Is there a possibility to add random strings in these names?

Comment: Do you mean, every time you run that particular scenario, it should pick random users behind the scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I didn't misunderstand, you can do this instead.

**Gherkin**

```
Scenario: Create random users
  Given I create "3" users
```

**FeatureContext**

```
var $str = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
var $status = [0, 1];
var $roles = ['authenticated user', 'admin', 'superman'];

/**
 * @Given /^I create "([^"]*)" users$/
 */
public function createDummyUsers($count)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $name = substr(str_shuffle($this->str), 0, 8);
        $status = $this->status[array_rand($this->status, 1)];
        $role = $this->roles[array_rand($this->roles, 1)];

        echo "You've just created $name - $status -$role" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

**Prints**

```
You've just created mqBWAQJK - 1 - superman
You've just created WYuAZSco - 0 - admin
You've just created HCNWvVth - 1 - admin

You've just created EmLkVRpO - 1 -superman
You've just created pxWcsuPl - 1 -authenticated user
You've just created mLYrlKdz - 0 -superman
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`RandomContext`](https://github.com/jhedstrom/drupalextension/blob/master/src/Drupal/DrupalExtension/Context/RandomContext.php) functionality from `drupal/drupal-extension` allows for usage like this:

```
Given I fill in "E-mail address" with "<?username>@example.org"
```

or

```
  Given users:
    | name        | email                   | status | roles         |
    | <?standard> | <?standard>@example.org | 1      | authenticated |
    | <?admin>    | <?admin>@example.org    | 1      | admin         |
```

Each token (eg `<?username>`, `<?firstname>`) used in a feature will be randomly transformed with a (random string) value for that feature execution. This is implemented with the use of Behat's `@Transform` functionality, meaning that your tokens will be substituted before execution of that step - so it works to generate random inputs anywhere you might need to use random input as part of your feature.

You can reference the same token later in your feature, eg to verify that the random value input earlier has been returned correctly, and the randomly generated value will be recalled. So, the first and second usages of `<?admin>` in the example above will both be replaced by the same generated value.

If you are using `drupal/drupal-extension` then this can be enabled by adding `Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\RandomContext` to the enabled contexts in your `behat.yml`.

If you aren't using Drupal, then the source linked above will demonstrate how you could implement the same for your own usage.

Answer (score -1):

I've created a solution on that you can try.

https://github.com/JordiGiros/MinkFieldRandomizer

MinkFieldRandomizer is a random (with sense) information generator for filling browser form fields in Behat Mink Selenium tests. It brings the option to run your tests in a more realistic way changing the information you use to fill in the forms in every test you run.

You can easily add it to your project by Composer.

One example:

```
Then Fills in form fields with provided table
| "f_outbound_accommodation_name" | "{RandomName(10)}" |
| "f_outbound_accommodation_phone_number" | "{RandomPhone(9)}" |
| "f_outbound_accommodation_address_1" | "{RandomText(10)}" |
```

I hope you try it! 
And you're welcome to add new functionalities or fork it or do wathever you want.
Cheers

Comment: I don't know why someone down voted my answer... My open source library does what the user was exactly asking for.